# How to test Google Voice recognition effectively in android?

Tags: android, testing, voice-recognition, microphone, google-voice-actions

I want to test Google Voice Action([Google Voice Action](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/)) for my App in a android device.

I am able to record some word or sentence to a voice file, and play it in a android phone near the device I need to test, but I find the recognition is low, beacause some noise or influence.

So is there is good and  effective way to test the recognition on a android device?